# How to declare extension parameter on generic enums companions

Tags: generics, enums, kotlin, extension-methods, companion-object

I'd like to have `.MAX` on generic enums to represent the values count.

I tried to play a little but I couldn't figure it out.

When I write, for example, this:

`val Enum.Companion.MAX get() = enumValues().size`

It complains on `enumValues()` that

> Type inference failed: Not enough information to infer parameter T in
>
> inline fun > enumValues
>   ( )
>   : Array
>   Please specify it explicitly.

It makes sense, then I tried also:

`val <E> Enum<E>.Companion.MAX get() = enumValues().size`

It complains on the second `E`

> Type arguments for outer class are redundant when nested class is referenced

Is there a way?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to use a reified type parameter so that the actual enum type is used at each call site:

```
inline val <reified T : Enum<T>> T.MAX get() = enumValues<T>().size
```

Answer (score 0):

### Extend a generic Enum with a reified type

```
inline fun <reified T : Enum<T>> max(): Int = enumValues<T>().size

// Then call
max<MyEnum>()
```

#### Alternatively, you can add it to an instance of the enum

```
inline val <reified T : Enum<T>> T.max get() = enumValues<T>().size

// Then call
MyEnum.VALUE.max // or myEnumVal.max
```